# Angular Material Chips not firing selection change event

Tags: angular, angular-material

From Angular Material Chip [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api#MatChip), there is a event for when the chip is selected or deselected:

[image]

However, I am not able to get this event to fire in this stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3jpqtx?embed=1&file=src/app/chips-input-example.ts

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like by default this control works with keyboard input.

To make it work with mouse click use #chip="matChip" and call its select()

```
<mat-chip-list (change)="selectChange($event)">
    <mat-chip #chip="matChip"  (click)='chip.select()' value="foo" (selectionChange)="selectChange($event)" removable="true">
        foo
    </mat-chip>

    <mat-chip #chip2="matChip"  (click)='chip2.select()' (selectionChange)="selectChange($event)" value="bar" removable="true">
        bar
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: Thanks! If I may ask please, how did you find that info out? I would like to improve my self learning with Angular